# On importing a tikz picture including node and a large font feature into a tex file

Tags: tikz-pgf, fontsize, mdframed, standalone, tikz-node

I have a standalone tikzpicture described as below which works well:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\newcommand{\bigfont}{\usefont{T1}{cmr}{m}{n}\fontsize{100}{\baselineskip} \selectfont}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [line width=1](-1.5,-1.6) rectangle (1.5,1.6) (1.5,1.6);
\node at ( 0,0) {\bigfont{O}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

When run by pdflatex we get the following picture:

[image]

I saved the standalone file as FIGG.tex and call it in a book as below:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\mdfdefinestyle{exampledefault}{linewidth=1pt}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{my_TEXT}{TEXT}

\begin{document}
\begin{mdframed}[style=exampledefault]
\begin{my_TEXT}\textbf{[NICE]}
\begin{center}
\includestandalone[width=.5\textwidth]{FIGG}
\captionof{figure}{MY FIGURE}
\end{center}
\end{my_TEXT}
\end{mdframed}
\end{document}
```

However this main tex file does not like to show the figure giving me an error:

> 10
> Undefined control sequence.
> l.10 \node at ( 0,0) {\bigfont
> {O}};
> Do you know how to fix this to be able to call the FIGG in the main tex file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, `standalone`'s default setting `mode=tex` takes effect. Under this mode, `\includestandalone` works like `\input` so the file `FIGG.tex` is included, with its preamble skipped. Therefore the `\bigfont` defined in the preamble `FIGG.tex` is skipped, throwing error `Undefined control sequence ... \bigfont`.

There are two kinds of solutions:

- If you want to include `FIGG` as a source file, Then use `\usepackage[subpreambles]{standalone}` in the main tex file and compile it twice.
- If you want to insert `FIGG` as an image, then use modes like `buildmissing` or `buildnew` as in `\usepackage[mode=<mode>]{standalone}` (need `-shell-escape`) in the main tex file. Check the doc of `standalone` to see which mode best fits your need.